# The universal windows app designer doesn't appear?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I am new to Windows development in general and I am facing a problem that doesn't appear in any of my search results.

The problem is the designer of the universal windows app disappeared - became transparent except only the borders of the virtual device, when I was trying to change the theme of the application.

I think this screenshot will explain the problem better than me:

[image]

Does any one encounter this same problem and have solved it?

Comment: Hmm, that looks like the color scheme of VS2010.  It is not capable of supporting Store/phone apps, universal app development requires VS2013.  Never use a sledge-hammer and never ask questions at SO without mentioning details like that.

Comment: Thank you @HansPassant .

I'm using the last version of VS2013.

The problem has been solved. it was a rendering problem in my ATI VGA card. but i didn't understand what do you mean by "sledge-hammer"